Formation process of j-invariant formula
I have always been interested in j-invariant. And by chance, I read the part titled Toward a History of Nineteenth-Century Invariant Theory in the book Ideas and their Reception Proceedings of the Symposium on the History of Modern Mathematics.
If you read page 164 of Toward a History of Nineteenth-Century Invariant Theory, you will find the following passage:

Finally, the application to (10) of the identification equations in (11) generated $$ u=\alpha\epsilon-4\beta\delta+3\gamma^2, \tag{12}$$ an invariant of the binary quartic. As innocent as this may seem, it represented a fundamental breakthrough in the theory of invariants, for Cayley's method of hyperdeterminants had begotten an invariant of the binary quartic different from the invariant $$\alpha\gamma\epsilon-\alpha\delta^2-\epsilon\beta^2-\gamma^3+2\beta\gamma\delta \tag{13}$$ generated by Boole's method. Furthermore, as Boole discovered shortly after receiving the latter from Cayley in which he detailed this new finding, the binary quartic had yet another invariant $$(\alpha\epsilon-4\beta\delta+3\gamma^2)^3-27(\alpha\gamma\epsilon-\alpha\delta^2-\epsilon\beta^2-\gamma^3+2\beta\gamma\delta)^2, \tag{14}$$ a polynomial function of the invariants in (12) and (13).28 Thus, new invariants arose as special combinations of known invariants, and while this observation came to determine the course of nineteenth-century invariant
theory, neither Cayley nor Boole anticipated such developments in 1845. For Cayley, especially, the most immediate concern was to generate simple invariants, and by 1846, he had devised a new method for doing just that.

After reading the paragraph above, I was able to see that mathematicians Cayley and Boole studied invariants through the formula $S^3-27T^2$, which we can conveniently call $S=\alpha\epsilon-4\beta\delta+3\gamma^2$ and $T=\alpha\gamma\epsilon-\alpha\delta^2-\epsilon\beta^2-\gamma^3+2\beta\gamma\delta$, respectively. However, if we read the article on Wikipedia, we can see that the j-invariant is defined as $j=1728\frac{S^3}{S^3-27T^2}$. This makes me curious.
As I read the book, I was convinced that the mathematicians Cayley and Boole created the invariant called $S^3-27T^2$, but I did not understand the circumstances under which the j-invariant suddenly appeared. Ultimately, I'm curious about which mathematician came up with the invariant $j=1728\frac{S^3}{S^3-27T^2}$, with what background and to what end.

$S^3-27 T^2$ is a version of the discriminant of the resolvant (the cubic associated to the quartic), techniques that were "mastered" at that time.

About invariant $S^3−27T^2$, for readers who aren't acquainted with the subject, it is a version of the discriminant of the resolvant (the cubic associated to the quartic), techniques that were "mastered" at that time. About the birth of $j$ invariant, I have no idea, but I am sure that this isn't difficult to find (See for example St Andrews site about the history of mathematics)

@JeanMarie Hello, Thank you for your advice!

Also you may see the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.0810
